# How to implement ParaUnity plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, unity-game-engine, cmake, paraview

I'm trying to implement [this Paraview plugin for Unity.](https://github.com/RCBiczok/ParaUnity) I've spent the whole day just trying to get through the dev setup steps listed on that page. I've never used cmake before, have only taken a few comp sci classes, and have limited experience using the command prompt.  I'm hoping that someone can help me get through these instructions on my windows 10 machine.

So far on step 1 I've changed the first command from

> ./configure.exe -prefix "C:\Qt\4.8.5" -debug-and-release -nomake
>   examples -nomake tests -nomake demos -opensource -confirm-license

to

> C:\Qt\4.8.5\configure.exe -debug-and-release -nomake examples -nomake
>   tests -nomake demos -opensource -confirm-license

Subbing the first command because I was getting an error that '.' is not a valid command and removing the -platform option because I couldn't find a valid platform that the command accepted.  When I entered 'nmake' I got the following errors:

> c:\qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\codecs\qisciicodec_p.h(56): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qtextcodec.h': No such file or
>   directory qlatincodec.cpp
>
> c:\qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\codecs\qlatincodec_p.h(56): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qtextcodec.h': No such file or
>   directory qsimplecodec.cpp
>
> c:\qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\codecs\qsimplecodec_p.h(56): fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qtextcodec.h': No such file
>   or directory qtextcodec.cpp
>
> c:\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-msvc2003\qplatformdefs.h(53): fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qglobal.h': No such file or
>   directory qtsciicodec.cpp
>
> c:\qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\codecs\qtsciicodec_p.h(85): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qtextcodec.h': No such file or
>   directory qutfcodec.cpp
>
> c:\qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\codecs\qutfcodec_p.h(56): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qtextcodec.h': No such file or
>   directory
>
> Generating Code...
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"'
>   : return code '0x2' Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"'
>   : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return
>   code '0x2' 
>   Stop.

Note that I did add C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin into the PATH environment variable like he recommended.  Since this step was optional, I moved on to step 2 to see if I could get through that.

I ran mkdir build and cd build inside of C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit and then ran

> C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE="C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin\qmake.exe" ..

Changing the original command which had "Visual Studio 12 2013"

I got the error

> CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Program Files/ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Searched around online, found nothing I could understand on how to fix this error, and fixed it by making a copy of "CMakeLists.txt" in the ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit directory.  Ran it again and got the errors

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (include):   include could not find load file:
>
> ```
> C:/Program Files/ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit/Source/Checks/cm_c11_thread_local.cmake
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> C:/Program Files/ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit/Source/Checks/cm_cxx17_check.cmake
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:86 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> CompileFlags.cmake
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:89 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> C:/Program Files/ParaView 5.5.1-Qt5-Windows-64bit/Source/Checks/cm_cxx_features.cmake
> ```
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:92 (message):   The C++ compiler does
>   not support C++11 (e.g.  std::unique_ptr).

Which is where I now stand.  Any help on any of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing similar problems building and compiling ParaView and the ParaUnity-Plugin. 
I was not able to build Qt aswell. As a workaround I downloaded and installed Qt 4.8.7 from Anaconda.

Have you succeeded in building the plugin?

Comment: Noo, we ended up just building c# VTK visualization capability with [ActiViz](https://www.kitware.eu/product/activiz)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I'll go on trying and post detailed build instuctions when I succeeded.